# Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3+ and IO Board does not detect any USB devices on Yocto Poky

Tags: usb, compute-module-3, yocto

I have a Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3+ mounted on an IO board running Yocto Poky with linux 5.10.17-v7.

I've installed different usb modules and libraries trying to make CM3 detect connected USB device. I'm using a simple wireless keyboard as a test. Here is the related Poky configuration:

```
KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += "dwc2 g_ether usb_f_ecm"
MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS += "kernel-module-dwc2 kernel-module-g-ether kernel-module-usb-f-ecm"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " libusb1"
ENABLE_DWC2_PERIPHERAL = "1"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " linux-firmware"
```

Unfortunately, this did not help. When I run: `lsusb` I get an empty result (no error, no devices connected). When I run `ls -allh /lib/firmware | grep -i rt` I see different usb drivers present. Here are messages from the boot process:

```
journalctl | grep -i usb
Dec 16 17:25:18 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
Dec 16 17:25:18 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
Dec 16 17:25:18 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel: usbcore: registered new device driver usb
Dec 16 17:25:18 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
Dec 16 17:25:18 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
Dec 16 17:25:18 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Dec 16 17:25:18 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
Dec 16 17:25:18 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel: usbhid: USB HID core driver
Dec 16 17:25:18 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel: dwc2 3f980000.usb: supply vusb_d not found, using dummy regulator
Dec 16 17:25:18 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel: dwc2 3f980000.usb: supply vusb_a not found, using dummy regulator
Dec 16 17:25:19 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel: dwc2 3f980000.usb: EPs: 8, dedicated fifos, 4080 entries in SPRAM
Dec 16 17:25:19 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel: usb0: HOST MAC 11:22:33:44:55:66
Dec 16 17:25:19 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel: usb0: MAC 22:33:44:55:66:77
Dec 16 17:25:19 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel: dwc2 3f980000.usb: bound driver g_ether
Dec 16 17:25:21 raspberrypi-cm3 systemd[1]: Reached target Hardware activated USB gadget.
Dec 16 17:25:23 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel[193]: [    0.153120] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
Dec 16 17:25:23 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel[193]: [    0.153193] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
Dec 16 17:25:23 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel[193]: [    0.153271] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
Dec 16 17:25:23 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel[193]: [    1.968721] usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
Dec 16 17:25:23 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel[193]: [    1.968795] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
Dec 16 17:25:23 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel[193]: [    1.969428] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Dec 16 17:25:23 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel[193]: [    1.977270] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
Dec 16 17:25:23 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel[193]: [    1.977287] usbhid: USB HID core driver
Dec 16 17:25:23 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel[193]: [    6.636383] dwc2 3f980000.usb: supply vusb_d not found, using dummy regulator
Dec 16 17:25:23 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel[193]: [    6.643849] dwc2 3f980000.usb: supply vusb_a not found, using dummy regulator
Dec 16 17:25:23 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel[193]: [    6.753380] dwc2 3f980000.usb: EPs: 8, dedicated fifos, 4080 entries in SPRAM
Dec 16 17:25:23 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel[193]: [    6.815337] usb0: HOST MAC 11:22:33:44:55:66
Dec 16 17:25:23 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel[193]: [    6.823893] usb0: MAC 22:33:44:55:66:77
Dec 16 17:25:23 raspberrypi-cm3 kernel[193]: [    6.852014] dwc2 3f980000.usb: bound driver g_ether
Dec 16 17:25:25 raspberrypi-cm3 dnsmasq[224]: dnsmasq: unknown interface usb0
Dec 16 17:25:25 raspberrypi-cm3 NetworkManager[209]: <info>  [1608139525.1939] manager: (usb0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
```

As a test, I used the same CM3+, same board, same jumpers configuration and installed Raspbian on the CM. It detected the same USB device instantly (wireless keyboard). This is the result from `lsusb` from Raspbian:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 238a:8367 Maxxter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Any ideas what might be missing in my Yocto Poky linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out. In `local.conf` I also had:

```
ENABLE_DWC2_PERIPHERAL = "1"
```

and in `config.txt` I had:

```
dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=peripheral
```

which effectively meant my Raspberry Pi Compute Module was behaving as USB guest and was not detecting USB wireless keyboard.

After removing the lines above, CM3 detected the USB keyboard.